# Couple facts about fibers of a morphism of schemes

Tags: algebraic-geometry, schemes, affine-schemes

Let $f: X \to Y$ be a morphism of schemes, take $y \in Y$ and let $k$ be the residue field of $y$. 
We also have $i_y: \operatorname{Spec}{k} \to Y$. Then we can form a fiber product $Z$ which is the fiber product of $f$ over $y$.

I would like to know how to deduce the following facts.

1) How do we know that as a topological space $Z$ is $f^{-1}(y)$?

2) Take any $t \in f^{-1}(y)$. Is it always the case that $O_{Z, t} = O_{X, t}$?

Thank you!

Comment: 1) What is $R$ in this question? You do not define this. 2) Have you tried anything for question 1, perhaps with the universal property of the fiber product? 3) Have you done any examples for question 2? Even the case of a linear projection between affine spaces will be instructive.

Comment: 1) Typo has been corrected, thank you. 2) Yes, I have (tried to reduce it to the affine case and use the universal property) but I am still not quite seeing it...

Answer (score 4):

As a first step, reduce to the affine case. To start, we may assume $Y$ is affine: factoring $i_y$ as the composition of $\operatorname{Spec} k \to \operatorname{Spec} B\to Y$ we see that the fiber product of $i_y$ and $f$ is the same as the fiber product of $i_y':\operatorname{Spec} k\to \operatorname{Spec} B$ and $\overline{f}:X_{\operatorname{Spec} B} \to \operatorname{Spec} B$. Next, we can cover $X$ by open affines with open immersions $i_A:\operatorname{Spec} A\to Y$. As open immersions are stable under base change, we get that the morphism $\operatorname{Spec} A\times_Y \{y\}\to X_y$ is also an open immersion, and the schemes $\operatorname{Spec} A\times_Y y$ cover $X_y$. So it's enough to understand the affine situation.

In the affine case, our map $X\to Y$ can be represented as a ring map $f: B\to A$ where a point $\mathfrak{p}\in X$ maps to a point $f^{-1}(\mathfrak{p})\in Y$. Let $\mathfrak{q}$ be the prime ideal associated to the point $y$. We will proceed to compute the fiber product by intermediate steps (recalling that for a fiber diagram of affine schemes $\operatorname{Spec} R\to \operatorname{Spec} S$ and $\operatorname{Spec} T\to \operatorname{Spec} S$, the fiber product is the scheme $\operatorname{Spec} R\otimes_S T$ with the obvious natural maps). Consider the following diagram:

$$
\newcommand{\ra}[1]{\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\xrightarrow{\quad#1\quad}\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!}
\newcommand{\da}[1]{\left\downarrow{\scriptstyle#1}\vphantom{\displaystyle\int_0^1}\right.}
%
\begin{array}{ccccc}
Z & \ra{} & X_{\operatorname{Spec} B_\mathfrak{q}} & \ra{} & X=\operatorname{Spec} A \\
\da{} & & \da{} & & \da{} \\
\{y\} & \ra{} & \operatorname{Spec} B_\mathfrak{q} & \ra{} & Y=\operatorname{Spec} B\\
\end{array}
$$

Our first step is to localize both $A$ and $B$ at the ideal $\mathfrak{q}\subset B$. Geometrically, this corresponds to taking the fiber product along the map $\operatorname{Spec} B_\mathfrak{q} \to \operatorname{Spec} B$ in the above diagram. We then identify $X_{\operatorname{Spec} B_\mathfrak{q}} = \operatorname{Spec} A \otimes_B B_\mathfrak{q} = \operatorname{Spec} A_\mathfrak{q}$. We note that by the description of the ideals of $A_\mathfrak{q}$, this preserves the points in the fiber over $y$: prime ideals of the localization $A_\mathfrak{q}$ are exactly those that do not intersect the set we're localizing at, which is equivalent to the preimages of those prime ideals being disjoint from the complement of $\mathfrak{q}$, or equivalently contained in $\mathfrak{q}$.

We are now in the situation of $B_\mathfrak{q} \to A\otimes_B B_\mathfrak{q} := A_\mathfrak{q}$. In order to compute the next fiber product, we recognize the inclusion $\{y\} \to \operatorname{Spec} B_\mathfrak{q}$ as the map $\operatorname{Spec} \kappa(y) = \operatorname{Spec} B_\mathfrak{q}/\mathfrak{q}B_\mathfrak{q} \to \operatorname{Spec} B_\mathfrak{q}$. Therefore $X_y=\operatorname{Spec} A_\mathfrak{q}/\mathfrak{q}A_\mathfrak{q}$, and it remains to identify the prime ideals of this ring. By the correspondence theorem, these are exactly the prime ideals that contain $\mathfrak{q}A_\mathfrak{q}$. But these are precisely the prime ideals who's preimage under the map $B_\mathfrak{q}\to A_\mathfrak{q}$ is exactly $\mathfrak{q}$: that is, the points of $\operatorname{Spec} A_\mathfrak{q}$ which are mapped to $\{y\}$. So this step also preserves the points in the fiber over $y$.

As these two steps preserve the points in the fiber over $y$ and combine to produce the fiber over $y$, we are done: the scheme-theoretic fiber over $y$ has the same underlying topological space as the topological fiber over $y$.

For an alternate proof, [points of the fiber product $X\times_S Y$ correspond to quadruples $(x,y,s,\mathfrak{p})$ with $f(x)=g(y)=s$ and $\mathfrak{p}$ a prime ideal of $\operatorname{Spec} \kappa(x)\otimes_{\kappa(s)} \kappa(y)$](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/01JT). In our case, $\kappa(s)=\kappa(y)$ and so the tensor product is really just $\kappa(x)$, the prime ideal must be zero, and we see the correspondence we're after.

For question 2, I fear you did not actually do an example - I suggested a linear projection between affine spaces in the comments, and I stand by that assertion! Please try it yourself before looking at the details contained under the following spoiler:

> This is false in general. Consider $\Bbb A^2_k \to \Bbb A^1_k$ by the natural projection map.  Let $t$ and $y$ both be the origins in their respective spaces. Then $\mathcal{O}_{X,t}\cong k[u,v]_{(u,v)}$, while $\mathcal{O}_{Z,t} \cong k[v]_{(v)}$, which are obviously not isomorphic - their maximal ideals have different numbers of generators, for one. In general, this is rare - it requires $y$ being an isolated point or $t$ having an open neighborhood inside $X$ which is entirely contained inside $Z$.

Comment: Thank you very much for this explanation! I am currently going through the details. Regarding question 2, I actually did do an example but I have not done the one you mentioned yet. I will make sure to do it before looking at it. Thank you.