# fibre with only one point is isomorphic to the spec of a field

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, affine-schemes, fibre-product

Let $R$ and $T$ be commutative rings with unity. Let $Q$ be a prime ideal of $R$ and $\phi:R \to T$. Suppose  $T \otimes_R (R_Q/Q R_Q)$ has only one prime ideal.
Then I would like to prove that the vertical map on the left hand side of
\begin{array}{cc}   
T \otimes_R R_Q/Q R_Q & \leftarrow & T
\\ 
\uparrow &   &\uparrow
\\
R_Q/Q R_Q & \leftarrow & R
\end{array}
is an isomorphism. How can I prove this?

I thought I could prove this by showing that given any $t \otimes r$, we have
$t \otimes r = 1 \otimes s$ for some $s \in R_Q/Q R_Q$, but this seems to only work if $t$ is in the image of $\phi$...

Edit. The question as asked does not seem to be correct, as can be seen in the comment. What assumptions can I add to make this true? I am trying to understand the details of a proof in Mumford [the fibre of $f$ over $y$ is $\operatorname{Spec} \kappa(y)$ given $f^{\#}(\mathfrak{m}_y) O_{X,x} = \mathfrak{m}_x$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3774335/the-fibre-of-f-over-y-is-operatornamespec-kappay-given-f-math?noredirect=1&lq=1). Thank you

Comment: "commutative diagrams with unity" — did you mean commutative rings?

Comment: Maybe I am misunderstanding, but what happens if $R$ is the zero ring?

Comment: What about $R=k[X]$ with $Q=(X)$ and $T=k[X,Y]/(Y^2-X)$. Then $R_Q/QR_Q=k[X]/(X)=k$ and $T\otimes_R R_Q/QR_Q=k[X,Y]/(Y^2-X)\otimes_{k[X]}k=k[Y]/(Y^2)$ which is not a field.

Comment: @lisyarus typo fixed, thank you

Comment: @AlexYoucis By assuming $R$ has a prime ideal $Q$, I'm avoiding $R$ is the zero ring

Comment: @Roland Thank you. I've added an edit to the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lemma: Let $f:X\rightarrow Y$ be a morphism of schemes. Then $f^{-1}(p) \cong X\times_{Y} \kappa(p)$ as sets where $\kappa (p)$ is the residue field at $p\in Y$.

Proof: Assume $X=\operatorname{Spec}A,Y=\operatorname{Spec}B$ are affine and $p\in \operatorname{Spec} B$. Set $S=B\backslash p$.  Then we have the following 1-1 correspondences
$$f^{-1}(p)\leftrightarrow\{P\in \operatorname{Spec}A : P\cap B=p \}\leftrightarrow \{P \in \operatorname {Spec}A : P\supseteq pA \ , \ P \cap {B\backslash p}=\phi  \} $$ $$\leftrightarrow \operatorname {Spec} \frac{S^{-1}A}{pS^{-1}A} \cong \operatorname {Spec} A\otimes_ B \frac{B_p }{pB_p}=X\times_Y \operatorname {Spec}\kappa(p) $$

Now you use a patching argument to complete the proof.

So you are asking when $\frac{A_p }{pA_p}$ is a field assuming $\operatorname {Spec} \frac{A_p}{pA_p}$ is a singleton. Let $P\in \operatorname {Spec} {A}$  be the unique prime ideal such that $P\cap B\backslash p =\phi $ and $P\supset pA$. Then $\frac{A_p }{pA_p}$ is a field iff $pA_p =PA_p$, namely the maximal ideal of $\mathcal O_{Y,p}$ generates the maximal ideal of $\mathcal O_{X,P}$ which is precisely what's given in the question you linked.

Comment: Thank you very much for this! This shows that $S^{-1}A/ p S^{-1}A$ is indeed a field. Is there a way to see that this is isomorphic to $B_p/p B_p$?

Comment: This need not be the case always. Simply look at $\operatorname{Spec}L \rightarrow \operatorname{Spec k}$ where $L|_k$ has positive transcendence degree. However if the residue field is agebrically closed and the morphism is of finite type, then you can use the weak nullstellensatz to conclude the isomorphism

Comment: This makes a lot of sense, thank you!